# What information, if not shared before the wedding, can invalidate the marriage?

Tags: halacha, marriage

I know that under certain situations, if you didn't share certain information prior to marriage, the marriage could be nullified and not even require a get.

What sort of witheld information qualifies for the above nullification of the marriage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marrige is nullified if there was fraud (i.e. you got married on condition that she has no blemishes but she did then it is nullified).

But there are **requirements to share** anyway (even though it does not completely nullify the marrige if you do not).

By the **girl** it is mumim (defects) that the boy could not have found out about.

Only the defects listed: [shulchan aruch even ezer 39.4](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.39.4?with=all),
[Rambam Bais hamikdosh 7 and 8](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008248/jewish/Biat-Hamikdash-Chapter-7.htm),
and vows [Shulchan aruch even ezer 117.3](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.117.3?with=all),
and her virginity status and her hyman status [shulchan aruch even ezer 67](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.67.5?with=all).
  (Infested tree I understand means broken hymen.)

---

By the **boy** only major defects (i.e. missing a limb (things the woman can say are unbearable for her) [shulchan aruch even ezer 154.1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.154.1)) (I heard that it was decided that homosexuality is one of them.)
But it might be that since a man is usually in public she should have known about his defects (since he does not hide them).

Wetting his bed is not a defect for men (for woman it might be) [shulchan aruch even ezer beer haitv on 39.4](http://www.sefaria.org/Be'er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.39.4?with=all)

---

It might still be considered a marriage out of doubt (need a divorce) if there were no conditions.

Comment: What's meant by "a smell"? Can't she smell him when they're going out?

Comment: @AniYodea My mistake

Comment: @AniYodea See Bais Shmuel (even just the shulchan aruch) that a woman can hide a bad smell even in the bathhouse http://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel.39.14?with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Even%20HaEzer

Comment: You don't need to place spacing between every line - it's distracting.

Comment: @AniYodea I do not know how to add a line (write on the next line) without spacings

Comment: You can force a line wrap by putting two spaces at the end of the line. Its covered in the [linebreaks](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks) in the editing help.